# Angular 8 : Merging two objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a couple of objects inside of an array :

```
array1 =[{name : "Cena", age : 44},{job : "actor", location : "USA"}]
```

is there a way for me to merge these two objects to get something like :

```
array2 =[{name : "Cena", age : 44, job : "actor", location : "USA"}]
```

I tried looping through the elements but it is not a good option if the object is a big one, I guess. Any good solution using typescript?

Comment: `Object.assign({}, ...array1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const array1 = [{ name: "Cena", age: 44 }, { job: "actor", location: "USA" }];
const array2 = [array1.reduce((acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, ...cur }))];
console.log(array2);
```